# OpenGL glMultiDrawElementsIndirect with Interleaved Buffers

Tags: c++, opengl, opengl-4

Originally using `glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex` to draw the scene meshes. All the meshes vertex attributes are being interleaved in a single buffer object. In total there are only 30 unique meshes. So I've been calling draw 30 times with instance counts, etc. but now I want to batch the draw calls into one using `glMultiDrawElementsIndirect`. Since I have no experience with this command function, I've been reading articles here and there to understand the implementation with little success. (*For testing purposes all meshes are instanced only once*).

The command structure from the OpenGL reference page.

```
struct DrawElementsIndirectCommand
{
    GLuint vertexCount;
    GLuint instanceCount;
    GLuint firstVertex;
    GLuint baseVertex;
    GLuint baseInstance;
};

DrawElementsIndirectCommand commands[30];

// Populate commands.
for (size_t index { 0 }; index < 30; ++index)
{
    const Mesh* mesh{ m_meshes[index] };

    commands[index].vertexCount     = mesh->elementCount;
    commands[index].instanceCount   = 1; // Just testing with 1 instance, ATM.
    commands[index].firstVertex     = mesh->elementOffset();
    commands[index].baseVertex      = mesh->verticeIndex();
    commands[index].baseInstance    = 0; // Shouldn't impact testing?
}
// Create and populate the GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER buffer... bla bla
```

Then later down the line, after setup I do some drawing.

```
// Some prep before drawing like bind VAO, update buffers, etc.
// Draw?
if (RenderMode == MULTIDRAW)
{
    // Bind, Draw, Unbind
    glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, m_indirectBuffer);
    glMultiDrawElementsIndirect (GL_TRIANGLES, GL_UNSIGNED_INT, nullptr, 30, 0);
    glBindBuffer(GL_DRAW_INDIRECT_BUFFER, 0);
}
else
{
    for (size_t index { 0 }; index < 30; ++index)
    {
        const Mesh* mesh { m_meshes[index] };

        glDrawElementsInstancedBaseVertex(
            GL_TRIANGLES,
            mesh->elementCount,
            GL_UNSIGNED_INT,
            reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(mesh->elementOffset()),
            1,
            mesh->verticeIndex());
    }
}
```

Now the `glDrawElements...` still works fine like before when switched. But trying `glMultiDraw...` gives indistinguishable meshes but when I set the `firstVertex` to `0` for all commands, the meshes look almost correct (at least distinguishable) but still largely wrong in places?? I feel I'm missing something important about indirect multi-drawing?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
//Indirect data
commands[index].firstVertex     = mesh->elementOffset();

//Direct draw call
reinterpret_cast<GLvoid*>(mesh->elementOffset()),
```

That's not how it works for indirect rendering. The `firstVertex` is not a byte offset; it's the *first vertex* index. So you have to divide the byte offset by the size of the index to compute `firstVertex`:

```
commands[index].firstVertex     = mesh->elementOffset() / sizeof(GLuint);
```

The result of that should be a whole number. If it wasn't, then you were doing unaligned reads, which probably hurt your performance. So fix that ;)